# String to JSON array of json objects

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a Sring s (JSON array) `[{"Phonetype":"Pre","Phone":"918282311"},{"Phonetype":"pre","Phone":"918333222"}]`

and now i want to convert this string to JSON array of the JSON objects.

in my code i only can create a JSONrray of objects...

```
@Override
    public ArrayList<TelephoneNumber> convertToAttribute(String s) {
        ArrayList<TelephoneNumber> list = new ArrayList<TelephoneNumber>();

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray arr = null;
        try {
            arr = (JSONArray) parser.parse(s);
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (JSONObject jo: arr) 
        {   
            System.out.println("obj  " +jo.get("Phone");

        }
        //create a list
        return list;
    }
```

how create a JsonArray of JsonObjects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using Gson to parse json values and use `FieldNamingPolicy` on a `GsonBuilder` to get a `Gson` object that handles upper camel case names correctly:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
            .create();


Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<TelephoneNumber>>() {}.getType();
List<TelephoneNumber> numbers = gson.fromJson(jsonArray, listType);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide). It is a series of Java classes written by The Google Overlords that handles serializing and deserializing JSON from and to Java classes.

So, making a few assumptions about what your `TelephoneNumber` class looks like, you should be able to do this:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<TelephoneNumber>>() {
                    }.getType();
ArrayList<TelephoneNumber> yourList = new Gson().fromJson(s, listType);
```

Then return `yourList`....

Comment: Thanks @Tom Mac. But the fields appears Null. fist i print the list and give me [DN_Schema.TelephoneNumber@64616ca2, DN_Schema.TelephoneNumber@13fee20c] . then a trie print a 2 fields each Telephone and appears NULL