# String to JSON array using Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

This question is similar to [string-to-json-array-of-json-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256105/string-to-json-array-of-json-objects). I have the following string:

```
"[{'Phonetype':'Pre','Phone':'918282311'},{'Phonetype':'pre','Phone':'918333222'}]"
```

How to convert this string to an array of objects using node?

Am reading data from a CSV file using [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson). Excel sheet contains a field phoneNumber. This field contains the above mentioned data. Am getting this data as string from the csv file. I want the data as JSON.

I tried `JSON.parse(string)`. But I got the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Code:

```
csv().fromFile(csvFilePath)
.then((jsonObj)=>{
    var a = jsonObj[0].phoneNumber;
    console.log(a);
    console.log(JSON.parse(a));
});
```

Here `console.log(a)` prints `[{'Phonetype':'Pre','Phone':'918282311'},{'Phonetype':'pre','Phone':'918333222'}]` as a string. When I try to convert into array of objects in the next line, it throws exception.

Comment: If that is a string then it **is** a JSON array already.

Comment: @Li357 — It's entirely possible that the OP intended to ask for that though. Their question doesn't really make sense in its current form.

Comment: If you want the data as a JavaScript array (rather than a JSON array), why not use a CSV library designed to *just parse CSV*? Why convert it to JSON and then convert it (again) to JavaScript?

Comment: "But I got the following error" — I don't get that error: http://jsbin.com/joharosehe/1/edit?js,console — perhaps `string` doesn't contain the value you think it does.

Comment: Please read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation) and update your question accordingly as it is really unclear. JSON *is* a string by definition.

Comment: For your third comment @Quentin , I believe that the CSV he is parsing has a column that contains JSON. His error could be from trying to parse the column heading (if the CSV has a heading row) or any single row that has invalid JSON in a loop.

Comment: Question updated with code I tried. @Li357

Comment: The string you currently have is invalid JSON (it is a valid syntax for javascript object literal syntax however it is invalid JSON data format). The character `'` is an invalid token in JSON. You need `"`

Comment: In the CSV document it is `'`. And I cannot edit that. So is there anything I can do in the coding side to get it as JSON? @slebetman

Comment: Then it is not JSON. It is javascript syntax. You have two choices: 1 write your own parser and parse the input byte-by-byte. 2 use eval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it contains 'single quotes' instead of "double quotes" then it is not valid JSON.

You will need to do a .replace(/'/g, '"')

```js
console.log(JSON.parse("[{'Phonetype':'Pre','Phone':'918282311'},{'Phonetype':'pre','Phone':'918333222'}]".replace(/'/g, '"')));
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse works fine on that string.

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('[{"Phonetype":"Pre","Phone":"918282311"},{"Phonetype":"pre","Phone":"918333222"}]'));
```

Your data is already an object and doesn't need parsing, try

```
csv().fromFile(csvFilePath)
.then((jsonObj)=>{
    var a = jsonObj[0].phoneNumber;
    console.log(a);
    console.log(a[0].Phonetype);
    console.log(a[0].Phone);
    console.log(a[1].Phonetype);
    console.log(a[1].Phone);
});
```

Comment: I have updated the string. String contains single quotes instead of double of quotes.

Comment: console.log(a[0]) prints only [ in the console. It is printing the character in the 0th position